# Deploy app in Release with AndroidEnvironment setup with XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin

I'm following this documentation [ransport Layer Security (TLS)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/)

When i deploy the android app into my device all the httpclient calls are working with TLS 1.1 or 1.2 .... but when i deploy in release or i archive in release signing the app i receive the error saying:

> xamarin Xamarin.Android returned no custom HttpClientHandler. Defaulting to System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

And then i receive an error from the server, because the server doesn't support TLS 1.0 .... that means httpclient is not working with AndroidEnvironment that i'm informing in EnvironmentVariables.txt file.

Could some one tell what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The setting for using the AndroidClientHandler can be different for Debug and Release configurations as this is a configuration dependent setting. Can you verify that you set the HttpClient Implementation to the AndroidClientHandler in Release configuration as well?

Comment: Hello @jgoldberger , i tested everything, i have the EnvironmentVariables.txt. Anyway, are you talking about this? -> [screenshot] (https://s15.postimg.org/5xh6qsb8b/2016_10_21_09h04_09.png)

Comment: For example, i put Debug configuration, Rebuild solution, then i deploy the app into my device, i test TLS 1.2 connection and works. But if i change to Release configuration , Rebuild solution, then i deploy the app into my device, i test TLS 1.2 connection and FAILS.